# Alamofire failing to import

Tags: swift, xcode, alamofire

I am working on a mobile app in Xcode 7.2 using swift 2.1. I installed Alamofire though cocoapods and in my podfile I specified Alamofire version 3.0 as shown below:

```
 source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
 platform :ios, '8.0'
 use_frameworks!

target 'SeniorSeminar' do
    pod 'Alamofire', '~>3.0'

end
```

After installing Alamofire, I opened up my .xcworkspace and tried importing Alamofire into one of my model files. I received the error: "No such module 'Alamofire'". I went and looked in the Podfile.lock and it shows that Alamofire version 4.0 was actually installed. I dont think version 4 is compatible with the versions of xcode and swift I am working in and I would prefer not to update either of these for fear of creating a ton of errors that I dont have time to fix. Does anyone have any suggestions on how to uninstall Alamofire -version 4 and forcing version 3 to install instead? Or are there any work arounds for why my project wont let me import Alamofire?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Delete you `pods` directory and perform a clean on your project.
- Change your podfile pod installation line to

`pod 'Alamofire', '3.0'`

- Install your pods again
- Perform a build! - Frameworks won't be imported until you build your project after installing them. Easy to forget.

Answer (score 0):

> I Hope you followed All the Steps for Installing ** Alamofire** correctly and have latest version installed

**If Not Follow this Step First**

> Step 1 : `Pod init`
>
> Step 2 : `Open podfile`
>
> Step 3 : add this in your podfile `pod 'Alamofire'`
>
> Step 4 : `Pod install`

**Then Follow This Step:**

Step 1 :

> Import Alamofire

Step 2 :

> Keep on Pressing Build ( Cmd + B)

Step 3:

> If Issue Continues then just close your Current program for a moment
>   by completely closing it **(cmd + Q)** and then Re-start it and Follow
>   Step 1 & 2 This will work

Thanks